# Obtain combination of collections in functional style in F#

Tags: select, foreach, f#, functional-programming

Say we have a collection

```
let xs = ["1";"2"]
```

We can loop through its elements

```
let forXs =
    [ for x in xs do
        yield x ]
```

Or we can be more functional with `map`

```
let mapXsWithId = List.map id xs
let mapXLambda = List.map (fun x -> x) xs
```

Say we have a number of collections, each with potentially different lengths

```
let xs = ["1";"2"]
let ys = ["a";"b";"c"]
let zs = ["1";"2";"3";"4"]
```

We can obtain the combination of all the elements in this way

```
let combinations =
    [ for x in xs do
        for y in ys do
            for z in zs do
                yield x + y + z ]
```

Can we do this in a more functional way?

Comment: The way you demonstrated is quite functional. What do you see in it that is not functional enough for you?

Comment: With map, you have a tighter contract than for/foreach - you do the thing to all the things. With for/foreach, you can still do strange things. It's kind of like the progression from goto to loops. You give up power but make code more readable and predictable and less error-prone.

Comment: You can do the exact same strange things with `List.collect`. `for .. in` is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think I'm not quite there in my understanding of `collect`. It sounds like `List.map` constrains to a level that `List.collect` doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
let xs = ["1";"2"]
let ys = ["a";"b";"c"]
let zs = ["1";"2";"3";"4"]

let combinations =
    xs
    |> List.collect (fun x ->
        ys
        |> List.collect (fun y ->
            zs
            |> List.map (fun z -> x + y + z)))
```

The question is if that's much better than your solution.

Comment: Great answer. You said it @TeaDrivenDev, for...in...do...yield isn't THAT imperative and it reads really well.

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @TeaDrivenDev, putting the collection name (`xs`) on the same line as the operation (`List.`) makes it look more equivalent.

```
let combinations =
    xs |> List.collect (fun x ->
        ys |> List.collect (fun y ->
            zs |> List.map (fun z -> x + y + z)))

let combinations2 =
    [ for x in xs do
        for y in ys do
            for z in zs do
                yield x + y + z ]
```